# Add a row under specific column in datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, datatable

I Use the following code for load the sql table values into the datatable

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ExportExcel", con);
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        int total = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            int salaryvalue = Convert.ToInt32(row["Salary"]);
            total = salaryvalue + total;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add("Salary");
        dt.Rows.Add(total);
```

And I add Salary,total dynamically.But It Shows in first column one by one.

[image]

But I need salary in Department column,and total in Salary Column.How to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
     dt.rows.add(new object[]{"","Salary",total });
```

Instead of calculating Total you can use `Datatable.Compute Method`

```
     object total;
      total= dt.Compute("Sum(Salary)", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

The ADO.NET information that you need for this can be found at msdn: [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx). You can either compute it in code, like you've done or insert a function in the excel document.

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

row["Name"] = "Salary";
row["Salary"] = total;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Hehe.. so funny, or sad really, that questions that can be easily answered (by looking up msdn) always get a ton of answers, and the ones that are hard get shunned cause there's no points/min to be had from them...

Answer (score 0):

You should write like this after your foreach loop,

```
DataRow drNew=dt.NewRow();
drNew[0]="";
drNew[1]="Salary";
dtNew[2]=total;
dt.Rows.Add(drNew);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to add only one row, so just add one row.

```
dt.Rows.Add(string.Empty, "Salary", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `*` in your query, that produces just nasty errors in future. Name all of your columns that you want to retrieve.

You have to add an empty string for the first column:

```
// dt.Rows.Add("Salary"); <-- remove
dt.Rows.Add("", "Salary", total);
```

By the way, you could also use following query to get the total count:

```
int total = dt.AsEnumerable.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Salary"));
```